# QGridLayout remove spacing

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, pyside

I have a `QTableWidget` and 6 `QPushBotton` i want to put them in a layout in this way

[image]

just a small spacing between Bottons

But Using `QGridLayout` make it looks like this

[image]

Code:

```
    tab_Memory_layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    tab_Memory_layout.setVerticalSpacing(0)
    tab_Memory_layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
    tab_Memory_layout.addWidget(self.MemoryTable, 0, 0)
    tab_Memory_buttons = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    tab_Memory_buttons.setSpacing(5)
    tab_Memory_buttons.addWidget(self.pushButton_add_memory, 0, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
    tab_Memory_buttons.addWidget(self.pushButton_up_memory, 1, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
    tab_Memory_buttons.addWidget(self.pushButton_down_memory, 2, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
    tab_Memory_buttons.addWidget(self.pushButton_top_memory, 3, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
    tab_Memory_buttons.addWidget(self.pushButton_bottom_memory, 4, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
    tab_Memory_buttons.addWidget(self.pushButton_delete_memory, 5, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
    tab_Memory_layout.addLayout(tab_Memory_buttons, 0, 1)
    self.tab_Memory.setLayout(tab_Memory_layout)
```

I tried the `setRowStretch(i, 0), setVerticalSpacing(0)` but it didn't help!

I also used `QGridLayout` and `QVBoxLayout` for the Bottons Group, it works but all Buttons are aligned at the Bottom, although i used `AlignTop` for each element and for the Layout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to add a **[Spacer](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qspaceritem.html)** in your layout:

[image]

*The **QSpacerItem** class provides blank space in a layout.*

```
verticalSpacer = QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
tab_Memory_buttons.addItem(verticalSpacer, 6, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
```

Any extra space in the layout will be "absorbed" by the spacer, which will keep other widgets aligned.

Answer (score 1):

Add a Qlabel("") below delete button. This makes them up like the way you want.

Comment: @FinalContest @user3051668
i think this may work if i used `tab_Memory_layout.addWidget(self.MemoryTable, 0, 0, -1, 1)`, then for all Buttons i set `rowspan = 1` and `columnspan = 1`, then add `Qlabel("")` and set `rowspan = 2` and `column = 1` or whatever, it will weirdly work!

Comment: @BenIshak: just do not use it. It is a big hack. :) The right way is using a spacer item as Tay2510 wrote it.

Comment: LOL, I use that strange method for years and it always works :)